# Klipper firmware on OctoPi asks for MCU for flashing

Tags: raspberry-pi, klipper

I have Marlin firmware on an Anycubic Vyper 3D printer and I want to use Klipper.

My Raspberry PI 3B runs OctoPi and I installed Klipper from Github. Now I want to flash Klipper, but when I select **Raspberry Pi** for flashing I get an error that flashing on Raspberry is not supported. For the attached Vyper printer I have no knowledge of the MCU to select.

What MCU to select in Klipper for Anycubic Vyper?

[image: Klipper_make_menuconfig]

Answer (score 1):

The printer controller board (the controller that came with the printer) needs to have the basics for being controlled by Klipper, hence the flashing, you should select the MCU of the 3D printer, that is not your Raspberry PI. Usually it is a Atmega AVR or a 32-bit controller board.

It appears the Anycubic Vyper 3D is using a 32-bit Cortex-M3 MCU, but please check what your controller has.

Please read [this article](https://m.all3dp.com/2/klipper-ender-3-v2/) by All3DP, it describes exactly the same as above:

> Use your device’s arrow keys and enter button to navigate the pop-up menu, and go to the “Micro-controller section”.
> The Ender 3 V2 uses an STM 32-bit board, so click the “STMicroelectronics STM32” option.

Comment: Do i need to open the 3d printer in order to see the controller?

Comment: @Leder You may want to do that, but I'm convinced that you have a 32-bit board.